# Get an ABI from an interface

Tags: web3.py

Can I get the ABI from an interface?

Let's say I have a file named `ContractInterfaceExample.sol`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity 0.6.12;
interface ContractInterfaceExample {
 
  function doStuff(bool val) external;
}
```

Can I get the ABI from this in web3.py?

```py
# something like
import ContractInterfaceExample.sol?

w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(os.getenv('RPC_URL')))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=???)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my method:

```
async def DEXFetchAbi(addr):
    try:
        url = abiurl
        params = {
            "module": "contract",
            "action": "getabi",
            "address": addr,
            "apikey": abiurltoken }   
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}   
        resp = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()
        abi = resp["result"]
        if(abi!=""):
            return abi
```

with
addr= 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E ( pancake swap https://bscscan.com/address/0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E)
abiurltoken = API from https://bscscan.com
the header might be needed if you try to get it on testnet otherwise it can be ignored.